# issue at downloading torrents java

Tags: java, bittorrent

I'm trying to build a java torrent downloader, based on [ttorrent](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent) java library (link goes to docs and basic instructions).

I followed the instructions listed in the javadoc , exactly as they are. When running the code, notthing appears to happen. No exceptions either. And obviously the file is not downloaded, I can't even see a ".part" file in my downloads folder. Stays at 0%.

This is my code so far (compare it with the code in the docs).

```
 Client client = new Client(

                     InetAddress.getLocalHost(),

                     SharedTorrent.fromFile(
                             new File(TORRENTPATH),
                             new File(MKPATH)));

             client.download();
             client.waitForCompletion();
```

I didn't find any better documentation of ttorrent than that one. What am I doing wrong? And of course, the torrent has seeds because I downloaded it before from another torrent manager.

**UPDATE**: Although nothing is downloaded, the download process appears to start but throws the following log message:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried walking through the library code with a debugger?

Comment: No. I also don't know how to do so. Would that be useful to me?

Comment: Making sure ```download()``` actually triggers a download will definitely reveal your problem; it just takes some work to dig into. You tested this with a known good torrent, right? Something like a Linux distro?

Comment: Either ttorrent didn't support UDP tracker or your torrent file is bogus, per your log it appears to have an invalid port set up

Answer (score 1):

I know that the examples there aren't great, but here is one that will be a good starter point for you:

TorrentTest.java

```
import jargs.gnu.CmdLineParser;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

import com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client;
import com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client.ClientState;
import com.turn.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent;
public class TorrentTest {

    public static final String DEFAULT_TRACKER_URI = "http://localhost:6969/announce";

    /**
     * Display program usage on the given {@link PrintStream}.
     * 
     */
    private static void usage(PrintStream s) 
    {
        s.println("usage: SimpleClient [options] torrent");
        s.println("Leech and seed this torrent file.");
        s.println();
        s.println("Available options:");
        s.println(" -h,--help               Show this help and exit.");
        s.println(" -o,--output DIR         Output directory for file.");
        s.println();
    }

    /**
     * Main program function.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser();
        CmdLineParser.Option help = parser.addBooleanOption('h', "help");
        CmdLineParser.Option outputString = parser.addStringOption('o', "output");

        try {
            parser.parse(args);
        } catch (CmdLineParser.OptionException oe) {
            System.err.println(oe.getMessage());
            usage(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
        }   

        // Display help and exit if requested
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals((Boolean)parser.getOptionValue(help))) {
            usage(System.out);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Get options
        File output = new File((String) parser.getOptionValue(outputString, "."));

        // Check that it's the correct usage
        String[] otherArgs = parser.getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 1) {
            usage(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Get the .torrent file path
        File torrentPath = new File(otherArgs[0]);

        // Start downloading file
        try {
            SharedTorrent torrent = SharedTorrent.fromFile(torrentPath, output);
            System.out.println("Starting client for torrent: "+torrent.getName());
            Client client = new Client(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), torrent);

            try {
                System.out.println("Start to download: "+torrent.getName());
                client.share(); // SEEDING for completion signal
                // client.download()    // DONE for completion signal

                while (!ClientState.SEEDING.equals(client.getState())) {
                    // Check if there's an error
                    if (ClientState.ERROR.equals(client.getState())) {
                        throw new Exception("ttorrent client Error State");
                    }

                    // Display statistics
                    System.out.printf("%f %% - %d bytes downloaded - %d bytes uploaded\n", torrent.getCompletion(), torrent.getDownloaded(), torrent.getUploaded());

                    // Wait one second
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }

                System.out.println("download completed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("An error occurs...");
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            } finally {
                System.out.println("stop client.");
                client.stop();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("An error occurs...");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is working barely well. I tried it and is far better of what I proposed, so really thanks for that. I think it has an issue (i just think, maybe i'm wrong): at running the code, the console throws several warnings about peers that timed-out, or "could not connect to peer: connection refused". Therefore, the download is really slow (and I tried it in torrents with no lack of seeds).

Comment: Another thing: the smaller the file, the better this code works. The torrent file I want to download is 153 MB , it reaches 50% really fast, but between 51% and 100% it becomes quite slower. -@Kyllopardiun

Comment: @Sebastian96, that's how ttorrent works, unless you edit the plugin itself. You are really unlikely to get a better result than this.